# Error: Can't resolve 'constants' in constants-fs

Tags: angular, typescript, browserify

I installed a js package [fs-constants](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fs-constants) that uses  the next line in its browser.js file.

```
module.exports = require('constants')
```

I get this error on compiling

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/fs-constants/browser.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'constants' in '/mnt/c/Users/jbermudez/workspace/HMI_WEB_CONVERTIDORES/front/node_modules/fs-constants'
```

I checked that i have a package installed called constants-browserify but it seem not resolve the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the `fs-constants` module is relying on another module called constants, which is now depreceated, as the npm site of the module itself states. This is now called using `require("fs").constants`, however this is node-only. Which Node version are you on? As of `v12.18`, the constants module still exists and is callable for me.

Comment: 14.0  

I see, as you stated that the non browser mentions uses module.exports = require('fs').constants || require('constants') , but the same sentence in the browser,js not  solves the issue